# Запись данных в текстовый файл C++

Tags: c++, текстовые-файлы

Имеется текст с кол-вом строке <=100. Я написал две функции для чтения и  записи в выходной файл данных в обратном лексикографическом порядке. В рамках функции main все работало, но после создания нескольких функций запись перестала работать. Удалось выяснить, что передается n=0 в функцию write, но даже если указать другое число, цикл заканчиается на первом слове. так ничего и не записав.

Все в единой функции:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Word
{
    char str[90];
};
Word *Sort(Word *obj,int n)
{
    Word *data=new Word[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=n-1;j>i;j--)
        {
            if(obj[j-1].str[0]<obj[j].str[0])
            {
                strcpy(data[0].str,obj[j].str);
                strcpy(obj[j].str,obj[j-1].str);
                strcpy(obj[j-1].str,data[0].str);
            }
        }

    }
    delete [] data;
    return obj;
}
int main()
{
    int n=0;
    FILE *input;
    Word *obj=new Word[100];
    input=fopen(R"(input.txt)","r");
    if(!input)
    {
        cout<<"Unable to open file!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        while(!feof(input))
        {
            fscanf(input,"%s",obj[n].str);
            n++;
        }
        fclose(input);
    }
    obj=Sort(obj,n);
    FILE *output;
    output=fopen(R"(output.txt)","w");
    if(!output)
    {
        cout<<"Unable to open output file!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            fprintf(output,"%s\n",obj[i].str);
        }
        fclose(output);
    }
    cout<<"All done!\n\n";
    delete [] obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Раздельно:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Funcs.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    Word *obj = new Word[100];
    read(n, obj);
    write(n, obj);
    return 0;
}
```

```
//Funcs.h
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

struct Word {
    char str[90];
};

Word *Sort(Word *obj, int n);
tuple<int, Word *> read(int n, Word *obj);
void write(int n, Word *obj);
```

```
//Funcs.cpp
#include "Funcs.h"
Word *Sort(Word *obj, int n) {
    Word *data = new Word[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = n - 1; j > i; j--) {
            if (obj[j - 1].str[0] < obj[j].str[0]) {
                strcpy(tem[0].str, obj[j].str);
                strcpy(obj[j].str, obj[j - 1].str);
                strcpy(obj[j - 1].str, data[0].str);
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] data;
    return obj;
}

tuple<int, Word *> read(int n, Word *obj) {
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(R"(input.txt)", "r");
    if (!input) {
        cout << "Unable to open file!\n";
    } else {
        while (!feof(input)) {
            fscanf(input, "%s", obj[n].str);
            cout << "Word:" << obj[n].str << endl;
            n++;
        }
        fclose(input);
    }
    obj = Sort(obj, n);
    return make_tuple(n, obj);
}

void write(int n, Word *obj) {

    FILE *output;
    output = fopen(R"(output.txt)", "w");
    if (!output){
        cout << "Unable to open file!\n";
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            fprintf(output, "%s\n", obj[i].str);
        }
        fclose(output);
    }
    delete[] obj;
}
```

Comment: int n = 0; ... write(n, obj);  - ничего не смущает?

Comment: А почему Вы не используете возвращаемые функциями `read`,`write` значения? Вы изменяете значение `obj`, но потом это никак не используете.

Comment: @Виктор Я инициализирую переменную, затем изменяю её в функции и возвращаю с другим значением. По крайней мере я отталкивался от такого решения. Что не так?

Comment: @isnullxbh Разве в функции ```write``` в цикле ```for``` я не использую значение ```obj```? Мне необходимо это значение записать в файл, после чего я его удаляю.

Comment: @toryo просто Вы не где в main не изменяете переменную n (не присваиваете ей новое значение)

Comment: @Виктор я не понимаю, как мне присвоить n значение из функции, если кроме n я возвращаю ещё и obj. ```n = read(n, obj)``` не сработает ведь.

Comment: auto [n1, obj1] = read(int n, Word *obj);